# No sound from hardware with ASUS Eee PC 904HA Netbook

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, troubleshooting

My ASUS Netbook, running Windows XP SP3 is running perfectly except with one particular piece of hardware, a ADS USB Instant TV external adapter. When hooked up, I get a perfect picture and all is well, except there is no sound coming from the netbook. I should note, the sound works perfectly with all other applications. I had this particular piece of hardware hooked up to my desktop PC at one time and never had a problem with the sound. Only with the netbook. I'm hoping I'm just missing a setting somewhere. to turn the sound on. Molly?

Comment: Could it just be a driver issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you asking me??? :)

i'm not familiar with this USB TV Tuner, but i see on the spec sheet that it does feature audio out. that could mean the device installs itself as the default USB audio device when you plug it in. check the control panel > sound and audio devices (Audio) and set the Realtek soundcard as default.

Comment: I was directing the question in your direction:) I thought you owned this particular netbook, or are quite familiar with it...After plugging the TV tuner in and playing something on it, it still shows the Realtek as the default soundcard. I checked all available sound settings, but still no sound. Funny thing is, if I record what is showing on the TV tuner screen and play it back, there IS sound on the playback, so at least it records the sound. I went back to the software and installed what it called "USB Audio Driver" but all that did was screw things up and I had to go back and do a restore

Comment: did you install the barebone realtek driver or the full suite with the Realtek Control Panel/sound mixer?

Comment: As usual, you forgot more than I know...Went back and installed the full suite. Audio works fine now. Thanks a million!!!

Answer (score 0):

It can be cause of driver issue or check whether mute is off or check the volume settings.